# Null true expression not returning

Tags: ms-access-2010, isnull

I'm working in Access 2010. I want NULL values to return as 0 but I cannot get them to show up. The false values work fine. There should be 29 total rows, 20 returning 0 and 9 returning their value. Here is the code.

```
SELECT [QAT Export].Title, IIF(ISNULL(Count([QAT Export].[TaskID])),0,Count([QAT Export].[Task ID])) AS [Update Good]
FROM [QAT Export]
WHERE ((([QAT Export].[Task Status])<>"Closed" And ([QAT Export].[Task Status])<>"Cancelled") AND (([QAT Export].[Updated By]) <>"linker")AND((DateDiff("d",[Update Time],(Date())))<10))
GROUP BY [QAT Export].Title
ORDER BY [QAT Export].Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IIF() and IsNull() functions look fine.

Chances are: your WHERE clause is excluding the nulls through one of the tests in there.

What are the chances since [TaskID] is Null, [Task Status] is Null as well?
If that's the case, you'd need to test for IsNull([Task Status]) in your WHERE clause also.

Post your 29 records if you need more help.  Most likely the Data is causing your WHERE clause to drop those records.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm an idiot and just realized that none of the fields are going to be NULL. Therefore it's working fine, I just need to actually look for the right info. What I actually want is the records that haven't been updated within the last 10 days to return 0.